# Modify Transmitted data in Webview Control

Tags: javascript, c#, xaml, webview, uwp

I want to inject content into my web page called from WebView Control and the  html code is:

```
<section id="header" class="header-section section-padding">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="text-center">
                <h2 class="section-title">Text I Want to Change</h2>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

I tried this from [this tutorial](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/controls-and-patterns/web-view):

```
string functionString = String.Format("document.getElementById('header').getElementsByTagName('h2')[0].innerHTML = 'new text';");
await webView1.InvokeScriptAsync("eval", new string[] { functionString });
```

But this is generating error.I am not good in javascript so how do I change the text inside `h2` tag?

Xaml Code:

```
<Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <WebView x:Name="WebView"
             LoadCompleted="WebView_LoadCompleted"
             Source="http://info.vit.ac.in/gravitas2015/tg15/index.html" />
    <ProgressRing x:Name="ProgressRing"
                  Width="100"
                  Height="100"
                  Foreground="BlueViolet"
                  IsActive="True" />
</Grid>
```

Cs code:

```
private  async void WebView_LoadCompleted(object sender, NavigationEventArgs e)
{      
    string functionString = String.Format("document.getElementById('header').getElementsByTagName('h2')[0].innerHTML = 'new text';");
    await WebView.InvokeScriptAsync("eval", new string[] { functionString });
    ProgressRing.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;   
}
```

Error that i am getting:

```
System.Exception was unhandled by user code
HResult=-2147352319
Message=Exception from HRESULT: 0x80020101
Source=mscorlib
StackTrace:
     at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
     at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
     at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
     at WindowsApp2.Views.Organisers.<WebView_LoadCompleted>d__1.MoveNext()
InnerException:
```

To reproduce the issue:

1. Create a Template10 Hamburger Template
2. Add a  new xaml page say team.xaml and add this page to hamburger shell(a new hamburger button to navigate to this page)
3. In team.xaml copy my code.
4. Now run it and navigate to this page from hamburger Menu.
5. This will generate the above error.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: *"But this is generating error."* - You need to include the exact error message, along with the expected behavior as well as the observed behavior.

Comment: I can't reproduce your issue. Your code is right. How do you load your page into the` WebView` and when do you call `InvokeScriptAsync` method? Could you share a [mcve] that can reproduce your issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is that there is no `section` whose `id` is "header" in your html page:http://info.vit.ac.in/gravitas2015/tg15/index.html.

If we test the JavaScript code in web browser (e.g. Edge), we will find it will throw an error like following:
[image]

And this is the reason why we get exception while calling `InvokeScriptAsync` in code-behind. I'm not sure which `section` you want to change, but if you edit the JavaScript string like following, your code should be able to work.

```
string functionString = String.Format("document.getElementById('portfolio').getElementsByTagName('h2')[0].innerHTML = 'new text';");
```

Besides this, [**WebView.LoadCompleted** event](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.ui.xaml.controls.webview.loadcompleted.aspx) may be altered or unavailable for releases after Windows 8.1. Instead, please use [**NavigationCompleted**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.ui.xaml.controls.webview.navigationcompleted.aspx).